# Sorting in a right way numeric values separated by an apostrophe?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sorting, numeric

i have a table where i have some numeric records such as:

```
NET_SALES 
0 
0 
318 
1'200 
10'720 
12'812
-1'285 
13'682 
40'713
-4'170 
...
```

I´ve used:

```
TO_CHAR(Numeric field, 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.''''')
```

However, when i sort the field it doesn´t sort it in a right way, because first it should be shown the negative numbers, then the 0s and then the positive numbers. I know the problem is because now the field is character, but i would like to can separate by apostrophes and sort them in a right way.

I tried converting it TO_NUMBER again but the apostrophes disappear...

Is there any way to sort them?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR...  ORDER BY TO_NUMBER...?

Comment: What is the column data type? The question implies it's a number, in which case you'd just `order by numeric_field`; and if it's a string (a) why and (b) why use `to_char()`?

Comment: @Alex Poole, the column data type is a NUMBER and i convert to string to format the number adding the apostrophes to separate the thousands.

Comment: @jarlh The problem is i pass the query to a datagridview on .NET and the datagridview sorts the column clicking on the heading.

Comment: But why wouldn't you just sort the numbers when they are actually numbers? So the problem essentially isn't sql but the datagridview. (should probably tag that and change your question to reflect that).

Comment: Select both versions, order by TO_NUMBER.

Comment: @AlonsoGonzálezNestal - then that's nothing to do with the query. You're presenting it as a string, so your datagridview can only interpret it as a string. Why not retrieve it as a number and have the datagridview format it, instead of retrieving it as a string? (Or, order by the number in the query, and then... don't click the heading?)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, i tried that but the problem is the apostrophes on the number. Is there any way to add the apostrophes to the numbers of the sql field without casting to char?

Comment: Are you locking for this: `TO_CHAR(Numeric field, '999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.''''')`?

Comment: @AlonsoGonzálezNestal -the apostrophes (or more commonly commas; but any group and decimal separators etc.) are the *presentation* of the number. If you leave it as a numeric value the client is responsible for formatting it - your datagridview in this case. If you convert it to a string in your query the client has no way to know it was or represents a number. I'd really suggest you find a way for the the datagridview to format the number the way you want. (I have no idea how to do that; retagging might help find an answer).

Comment: @AlexPoole Finally i had to change the datagridview to support numbers in order to show the separation between the thousands.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
order by cast(replace(Numeric field, '''', '') as int)
```

Comment: Thanks but finally i had to change a property on datagridview on .NET because with the query i had nothing to do...